# .desktop application shortcuts stop working after restart or log in and don't appear as correct icons on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: reboot, .desktop, shortcuts, desktop-icons

I'm trying to create launcher icons on my desktop. I got them to work properly by creating a file with `.desktop` extension with suitable content, for example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Google
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox
Type=Link
URL=http://google.com
Icon=firefox
```

However when I log out or restart the system the file stops working. For some reason the system starts treating it as a normal text file, despite it having a `.desktop` extension.

I have tried giving the file execution permission and it does not seem to affect it in any way. I have also tried adding the file to `/local/share/applications/` directory but it didn't have any effect.

So, the `.desktop` file works during the current session, but stops working after re-boot.

Also I just noticed that when I create something else on the desktop with the text editor like `test.txt` the `.desktop` file starts working again (for that session).

After creation ( current session ):

[image: Firefox shortcut icon]

After re-booting / logging out/in

[image: text file with .desktop extension]

Comment: The correct folder to place .desktop files (if not on the ~/Desktop) would be `~/.local/share/applications/`, not `/local/share/applications/`.

Comment: Hi. I have allowed the launching of the file. As I said, the file works perfectly during the current session, but when i re-boot the system or log out, the file stops working and "Allow Launching" option is not available anymore. Another note is that my .desktop file is located in ~/.local/share/applications as you suggested, but again it did not help.

Comment: If it's in the .local folder, get properties on the .desktop file, enable "Allow executing file as a program". Edit your question and show me your .desktop file.

Comment: Hi. Picture added. the file in picture 2 now works for some reason. It opens firefox browser and google website as it should, but the icon isn't there and the .desktop extension is present. It works, but looks kinda funny/ugly.